# NHibernate sqlQuery - column aliases with question marks

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have sql queries with column aliases that contain question marks.
For example:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select 1 as \"test?\" from test_table").UniqueResult();
```

The following query throws exception

```
Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: []
```

Is there a way to escape the question mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue for this - [Question marks in column names are not escaped correctly](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2681)

Try using  backticks instead of escpaing double quote like below

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select 1 as `test?` from test_table").UniqueResult();
```

I have not tried it myself but above should work. If not, and if you are using MS SQL Server then try following as well

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select 1 as [test?] from test_table").UniqueResult();
```